# Convert dataframe column to concatenated string without double quotes

Tags: r, string

I have a data.frame like this :

```
df = data.frame(str_col = c("when xyz = 'some_string' then 'this_string'",
                            "when xyz = 'some_string2' then 'this_string'"))
```

I want to convert the str_col to a comma separated vector without double quotes like :

`c(when xyz = 'some_string' then 'this_string', when xyz = 'some_string2' then 'this_string')`

I was trying this: 
`str_vec <- paste(shQuote(df$str_col), collapse=",")`

But I get this:

```
[1] "\"when xyz = 'some_string' then 'this_string'\",\"when xyz = 'some_string2' then 'this_string'\""
```

I don't want the backslash or double quote . I am trying to construct an SQL query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `noquote` instead of `shQuote`:

```
str_vec <- paste(noquote(df$str_col), collapse=",")
```

which gives:

```
> str_vec
[1] "when xyz = 'some_string' then 'this_string',when xyz = 'some_string2' then 'this_string'"
```

---

If you want to elimenate the double quotes around the above result as well, you wrap it again in `noquote`:

```
str_vec <- noquote(paste(noquote(df$str_col), collapse=","))
```

which gives:

```
> str_vec
[1] when xyz = 'some_string' then 'this_string',when xyz = 'some_string2' then 'this_string'
```

Comment: i made a little error in the expected output i wanted . . there shouldn't be a comma between when, but I fixed it by adjusting the collapse argument in your answer. thanks !